# Ionization energy of a donator impurity in Si vs H ionization energy

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Why is the ionization energy of a donator in an $\mathrm{Si}$ semicondutor much smaller than in an $\mathrm{H}$ atom?

Answer (score 1):

Because ionizing the donor in silicon only moves the electron from the donor into the conduction band, while ionizing hydrogen requires moving the electron to "infinity". The donor's electron remains within the solid, far below the vacuum level.